# Notificações do Stackoverflow

Tags: novo-recurso

### Novo recurso

Ultimamente tenho pesquisado uma tecnologia muito interessante de navegadores WebKit sobre [notificações](http://jsfiddle.net/5DCcH/), pensei que poderia ser bem legal adicionar essa tecnologia no StackOverflow, por exemplo as vezes não ficamos com a janela do SO aberta e recebemos notificações mas não sabemos pois as vezes estamos fazendo outras coisas e essa funcionalidade seria bem interessante apesar dela funcionar somente em navegadores WebKit ela é muito funcional, e creio que a maioria dos desenvolvedores usam navegadores webkit na minha opinião, o que acham disso?

> Código extraído:
>   [Notificação chrome](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10854/notificacao-chrome) e com a
>   resposta de **Miguel Angelo**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O site [**Stack Apps**](https://stackapps.com/) (rodapé da página, à direita) possui diversos aplicativos de todo tipo (browser, smartphone, desktop) que usam a [API do StackExchange](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) para diversos fins. Uma busca por ["chrome notifications"](https://stackapps.com/search?q=chrome%20notifications) retornou alguns bons candidatos - não só pro webkit, mas pra outros browsers também. Exemplos:

- [Real-time desktop notifications for Stack Exchange inbox ( Chrome / Firefox )](https://stackapps.com/q/3780/11214)
- [Stack Exchange Notifier Chrome Extension](https://stackapps.com/questions/1592/stack-exchange-notifier-chrome-extension)
- [New Q! - Google Chrome Extension notifies you of new questions of interest and inbox messages (now with API v2.0!)](https://stackapps.com/questions/587/new-q-google-chrome-extension-notifies-you-of-new-questions-of-interest-and-i)

Não experimentei, então não sei avaliar qual é melhor, nem qual faz exatamente o que (uns notificam de mensagens, outros de respostas às suas perguntas, outros de perguntas novas nas suas tags favoritas, etc). Mas com sorte você achará um que atenda seus interesses.