# Há como me inscrever em uma pergunta (não minha) e ser notificado por futuras respostas e/ou comentários?

Tags: suporte

Às vezes eu gostaria de me inscrever em alguma pergunta para receber atualizações sobre futuras respostas ou comentários. Muitas vezes são perguntas que não sei responder mas gostaria de ver a resposta.

Às vezes acabo dando um *star* na pergunta, mas não acho que isso seja eficiente, já que posso acabar me esquecendo de verificá-la. Seria melhor se eu pudesse receber uma notificação no menu de notificações aqui do site.

É possível fazer isso?

Comment: Além do favorito ou RSS? Ou isto que talvez seria dup? https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1386/101

Answer (score 6):

Somente via "feeds RSS", exemplo nessa sua propria pergunta, tem um link do lado, veja:

> [image: feed]

Aonde está escrito "Question feed", se o teu navegador já tiver um plugin/extensão de feed é provavel que ele já detecte e mostre para ti na barra de tarefas ou de endereço um icone de feed clicável para se inscrever.

Para notificações no menu do site tem uns "apps":

- https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1147/3635

Pode encontrar mais "apps" úteis em:

- https://stackapps.com/

Tem para diferentes coisas, alguns ainda funcionam, outros não, só testando.